# Как выбрать записи, которые связаны со всеми записями из другой таблицы через many-to-many

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица developers и таблица projects связаны через dev_prj, как выбрать project над которым работают все developers и наоборот ни одного?

Comment: http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как-то так:

```
select projects.* from projects 
left join dev_prj on projects.prj_id = dev_prj.dp_prj_id
group by projects.prj_name
having count(dev_prj.dp_dev_id) = (select count(dev_id) from developers)
```

И вот так:

```
select projects.* from projects 
left join dev_prj on projects.prj_id = dev_prj.dp_prj_id 
where dev_prj.dp_dev_id is null
```